# Get total number of primitives from a GLTF file

Tags: c++, gltf

Is there a way to get the total number of primitives from a GLTF File?
I am working on an OptiX (Cuda-Based with C++ host code) project and after loading the scene from the GLTF file want to keep track of all intersections of rays with primitives in a Buffer with one float for each primitive.
For cudamalloc I would need the total quantity of triangles (our models will consist only of triangles).
Is it somehow possible to read this out of the file or has it to be done manually?

I couldn't find anything in the documentation.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: glTF primitives may contain many triangles — which do you mean? See [the specification](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/2.0/README.md#meshes). Assuming you've parsed the JSON in the file, count primitives by iterating over all meshes and counting their primitives. Count triangles by iterating over all primitives and summing the number of triangles in each primitive.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Thanks for your answer, just to clarify: I use the OptiX meaning of primitive, which in my case will be the number of triangles in the model.
I thought, that maybe there is a variable that stores the amount of triangles of a model in a gltf file which can be read out with a single command.

So it seems that i will have to iterate manually over the entire file?

Comment: No, there's no single variable with the total number of triangles. You'll need to iterate over the mesh primitives and sum the triangles of each. Note that technically the file could contain points or lines, in addition to triangles. The [gltf-validator](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Validator) can scan the file and output a report containing the number of triangles, if it's an option for you to use that.

**EDIT:** Also note that a single mesh could be reused several times in a scene. Up to you whether that counts as additional triangles!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As we wont have many different models, we will use the online validator and copy the number of triangles manually to our code.